# How to add not null constraint to existing column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, constraints, alter-table

I have table name called "Person" with following column names

```
P_Id(int),
LastName(varchar),
FirstName (varchar).
```

I forgot to give `NOT NULL` Constraint to `P_Id`.

Now I tried with following query to add `NOT NULL` Constraint to existing column called `P_Id`,

```
1. ALTER TABLE  Person MODIFY  (P_Id NOT  NULL);
2. ALTER TABLE Person ADD CONSTRAINT NOT  NULL NOT NULL (P_Id);
```

I am getting syntax error....

Answer (score 337, accepted):

Just use an [`ALTER TABLE... MODIFY...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) query and add `NOT NULL` into your existing column definition. For example:

```
ALTER TABLE Person MODIFY P_Id INT(11) NOT NULL;
```

A word of caution: you need to specify the *full* column definition again when using a `MODIFY` query. If your column has, for example, a `DEFAULT` value, or a column comment, you need to specify it in the `MODIFY` statement along with the data type and the `NOT NULL`, or it will be lost. The safest practice to guard against such mishaps is to copy the column definition from the output of a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTable` query, modify it to include the `NOT NULL` constraint, and paste it into your `ALTER TABLE... MODIFY...` query.

Comment: @ShaktiSingh What's the difference between `modify` column and `change` column?

Comment: @Positive why did you write `INT(11)` and not just `INT`? What is the effect of the `11` ?

Comment: The 11 is just an example, it sets the length of the P_Id. i am not sure if it is necessary to add it again even though you might not even want to change it.

Comment: @Pacerier with `change` you modify the column's name

Comment: @JavierP, I meant what is the difference between modify column and change with the same name?

Comment: @Pacerier There is no difference.

Comment: I had to specify the column name twice. This means: 
ALTER TABLE Person Person P_Id INT(11) NOT NULL Default 12345;
The default is just an example. The column name twice because first you tell which column to modify and then how it should be named after the edit.

Comment: @Victor `MODIFY` is also supported by Oracle. And PostgreSQL doesn't support `CHANGE` instead it provides an `ALTER [COLUMN]` statement.

Comment: @Gerard the (11) doesn't set the length (whatever that would mean), it changes the number of 0 to pad in front of an int when rendered with the 0 padded option. In other words it's irrelevant in 99.9% of cases, and also it's the default.

Comment: note to self: structured query language isn't a standard query language...

Answer (score 25):

Try this, you will know the difference between change and modify,

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE curr_column_name new_column_name new_column_datatype [constraints]

ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name new_column_datatype [constraints]
```

- You can change name and datatype of the particular column using `CHANGE`.
- You can modify the particular column datatype using `MODIFY`. You cannot change the name of the column using this statement.

Hope, I explained well in detail.

Comment: You perform MODIFY operation to change but reverse is not possible ?

Comment: Oddly I was getting an error (MySQL 5.6, Workbench 6.3) changing/modifying a column I'd named null_heart_rate_count, error was #1138, Invalid use of NULL value. I had to drop and add the column instead.

Comment: @NavrattanYadav I think he meant to say rename, not reverse

Comment: @WilliamT.Mallard I was getting the same error. In my case it was because the column was already containing a NULL value in one row. After changing values to somenthing other than NULL, the query performed successfully.

Answer (score 17):

Would like to add:

After update, such as

```
ALTER TABLE table_name modify column_name tinyint(4) NOT NULL;
```

If you get

```
ERROR 1138 (22004): Invalid use of NULL value
```

Make sure you update the table first to have values in the related column (so it's not null)