# no implicit conversion of nil into String (sponsorship )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am getting the above error and it says that it has to do with the "+". Please note I did not code the below page, but I was told to fix it. If someone could help that would be awesome.

## MYMOH Controller

```
 210. def sponsorships
 211. dbdc_client.materialize("cv__Recurring_Gift__c")
 212. #@gifts =Cv__Recurring_Gift__c.find_all_by_cv__Contact__c(current_user.convio_id)
 213. @gifts = Cv__Recurring_Gift__c.query("cv__Contact__c = '" + current_user.convio_id + "' AND Child_Status__c = 'Sponsored' and cv__Recurring_Gift_Status__c='Active'")
 214. @account = Contact.find_by_Id(current_user.convio_id)
 215. #@old_sponsorships = Child_Sponsorship__c.query("Sponsor__c = '" + current_user.convio_id + "' AND Status__c = 'Open'")
 216. @sponsorships = @gifts # + @old_sponsorships
 217. unless @sponsorships.nil?
 218.  #if we find sponsorships
 219.  @children = []
 220.  @sponsorships.each do | spons |
 221.    @photo = nil
 222.      unless spons.Child__c.nil?
 223.        @child = Child__c.find_by_Id(spons.Child__c)
 224.            @photoTest = Picture__c.query("Child__c='" + @child.Id + "' and Primary__c=true").first
 225.            @photo = @photoTest.Photo__c if @photoTest
 226.            if @photo.nil?
 227.              @attachment = Attachment.find_by_ParentId(@child.Id)
 228.              @photo = "<img src='https://c.na12.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=" + @attachment.Id.to_s + "' />" unless @attachment.nil?
             end
             #set an unused variable to carry the photo url
             @child.LastModifiedById = @photo
             #add child to array of children
             @children << @child
        end
  end
end

end
```

## FULL TRACE

```
app/controllers/mymoh_controller.rb:213:in `+'
app/controllers/mymoh_controller.rb:213:in `sponsorships'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:425:in `_run__3687996442544047678__process_action__3216127983448203575__callbacks'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails3/action_controller.rb:23:in `block in process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:353:in `perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails3/action_controller.rb:22:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:30:in `traced_call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:23:in `traced_call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/exception_notification-4.0.0/lib/exception_notification/rack.rb:28:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__790379348702901205__call__4407048364405463113__callbacks'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-timeout-0.2.4/lib/rack/timeout.rb:108:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `catch'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you post the line number included in the error message (or better yet, the entire error trace)?

Comment: @sixty4bit there you go!

Comment: Looks like `app/controllers/mymoh_controller.rb` is what we need to see

Comment: The problem is not in the code that you've shown. It appears to be on line 213 of `app/controllers/mymoh_controller.rb`

Comment: files have been updated

Comment: I think this means `current_user.convio_id` is `nil` meaning, the database entry for the `current_user` has no `convio_id`.

Answer (score 0):

@pref is not declared as a string just by assigning it " ".

Try this:

```
preferences = String.new
if !params[:prefgirl].nil?
    preferences = preferences + "Girl,"
end
.
.
.
@preferences = preferences
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting the code. If the stack trace is pointing to the right place, the error is here, where you're building a string like this:

```
"cv__Contact__c = '" + current_user.convio_id + "' AND Child_Status__c = 'Sponsored' and cv__Recurring_Gift_Status__c='Active'"
```

If `current_user.convio_id` is nil, you will get the error you cite. You should think about either guarding against `current_user.convio_id` being nil, or how that query should be built if it is.

A more Rubyish way to build that string, by the way, is using interpolation:

```
"cv__Contact__c = '#{current_user.convio_id}' AND Child_Status__c = 'Sponsored' and cv__Recurring_Gift_Status__c='Active'"
```

Answer (score 0):

The error specifically means that `current_user.convio_id` is `nil`, and Ruby will not convert `nil` to a string without being told directly to. The `+` concatenates strings if the object on the left side is a string.

It seems that your whole `sponsorship` action depends on the user having a `convio_id` If that is a field that **all** users should have you should add a `not null` attribute to it, and go through and add one to all that don't have one currently.

If a `convio_id` is an optional thing you should check at the beginning of the action if they have one ex-

```
def sponsorships
  if current_user.convio_id.nil?
    flash[:convio_id] = "User has no Convio ID" # optional message saying why we're redirecting
    redirect_to <somewhere else> and return
  end
  <rest of the code here>
```

To add a field as required in Ruby, ignoring the database, you would need to add this line in to your model, probably `app/models/user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  validates :convio_id, presence: true
  ...
end
```

This will make it so all users created through the website must have a `convio_id` to be valid and saved.

Comment: forgive me what is the not null attribute and where am i suppose to add it?

Comment: It would be in whatever your database is. For example MySql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305225/how-to-add-not-null-constraint-to-existing-column-in-mysql5-1 Before doing this, be sure to back up your database, if you have some sort of Database Admin definitely talk to them.

Comment: @JWORTH I'll add more to my question on how you can do this with Ruby, and not change the database, but it will only affect new users created through the website.

Comment: i think im going to use your redirect option, because I figured out what was wrong. Apparently there is an additional process of signing up. Once you sign up then you have to randomly save your profile, which then means you have FULLY created your user. Then that error goes away. Im going to add the redirect that way it will let a new user know what they have to do.