# Parent key not found workaround

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table **USER**

```
CREATE TABLE "USER"
  (
    USER_ID    INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    CREATED_BY INTEGER NOT NULL ,
  ) ;
ALTER TABLE "USER" ADD CONSTRAINT USER_PK PRIMARY KEY ( USER_ID ) ;
```

For this particular database, I need the CREATED_BY table to be a foreign key to USER_ID in the same table.

```
ALTER TABLE "USER" ADD CONSTRAINT USER_USER_FK FOREIGN KEY ( CREATED_BY ) REFERENCES "USER" ( USER_ID ) ;
```

Because of this constraint, my insert statement will always fail on the first user.

Is there a best practice for getting around this? Can I disable the constraint for the first user added and then re-enable the constraint?

Comment: Make it `NULL` instead of `NOT NULL`?

Comment: is USER_ID really an auto increment? you could make it null instead as suggested by others then once inserted update CREATED_BY to the userID that was inserted and then make it not null again.  If it is not auto incremented, just leave it as it is and repeat your USER_ID value for you CREATED_BY value in your insert statement

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your create table script, so that it accepts null values for created_by column. Then you can insert your first record(that has a user_id and a null for created_by). Logically someone in that User table has to be the root record(in other words admin or first-user whose record isn't created by someone else).

Comment: remove not null condition when you define the "created_by" column.

Comment: CREATED_BY INTEGER NOT NULL , becomes CREATED_BY INTEGER

Comment: I added an answer trying to type code in comments is bad practice. cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE "USER"
  (
    USER_ID    INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    CREATED_BY INTEGER ,
  ) ;
ALTER TABLE "USER" ADD CONSTRAINT USER_PK PRIMARY KEY ( USER_ID ) ;
```

If table exists this line makes the column NOT NULL or non nullable.

```
ALTER TABLE USER MODIFY CREATED_BY INTEGER NOT NULL;
```

[How to add not null constraint to existing column in MySQL5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305225/how-to-add-not-null-constraint-to-existing-column-in-mysql5-1)