# Modifying the null column for a specific row in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to modify a row, `marketing_schedule`, in my database to change the column to `NULL` to `NO`.

[image]

I've tried the command `ALTER TABLE permissions MODIFY marketing_schedule tinyint(1) NOT NULL;` as given in [How to add not null constraint to existing column in MySQL5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305225/how-to-add-not-null-constraint-to-existing-column-in-mysql5-1) but I get the error shown in the screenshot above. Any idea on why I'm getting this error and how I can go about fixing my problem?

Comment: If it's an `INT` column, how can you change its value to `NO`? That's a string, not an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update rows which have NULL's in marketing_schedule to have a value and run the `ALTER TABLE` command again.

Answer (score 1):

If your are providing the default not null then you have to provide default value
in query

These query run after the update , as answered by @slaakso

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` Modify `column_name` TINYINT(4) DEFAULT 1 NOT 
NULL;
```

OR

```
 ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE `column_name` `column_name` TINYINT(4) 
 DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL;
```

Here 1 is default value