# Update column to add a default and disallow null

Tags: mysql

I want to update a column with a default value. I do that like so:

```
ALTER TABLE  `db`.`tbl` ALTER COLUMN `some_timestamp` SET DEFAULT current_timestamp();
```

that works fine. I also want to add NOT NULL. How do I do that?

Comment: find solution from this page , how to add not null https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305225/how-to-add-not-null-constraint-to-existing-column-in-mysql

Comment: check this page for adding not null constrain https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305225/how-to-add-not-null-constraint-to-existing-column-in-mysql

Comment: So I can't simply add this not null constraint. I have to rewrite the entire column definition? Ok - thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so:

```
ALTER TABLE `db`.`tbl` MODIFY `some_timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp();
```

`ALTER COLUMN` is only used for setting defaults in MySQL; `MODIFY <colname> <colspec>` modifies a column spec but doesn't rename it. To rename also, use `CHANGE <oldname> <newname> <colspec>` and specify oldname newname

Answer (score 0):

you can add multiple constrains by following way also
ALTER TABLE MEMBER
ADD CONSTRAINT U_MEMBERID UNIQUE(MEMBER_ID), primary key (MEMBER_ID),
CONSTRAINT Sys_date DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR Sys_date;